# Is static Initializer in JAVA a closure

Tags: java, groovy, static, closures, static-initialization

I was wondering if static Initializer in Java as shown below is a closure which groovy built on to implement the language.

```
public class className{
   static{

   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: To rephrase you want to know if Groovy (the whole language?) is based upon Java static initializers?

Comment: Java uses -> for lambdas, so anything without -> is obviously not a lambda.

Answer (score 7):

No. That is a block. Groovy also has these.

```
class A {
  static {
    println "static init block"
  }

  {
    println "init block"
  }

  def closure = {
    println "closure field"
  }
}

a = new A()
```

The code above will print:

```
$ groovy Block.groovy 
static init block
init block
```